# Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects - .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am receiving the below error message in my Apache log after cloning the git repo on our dev server;

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
>   configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the
>   limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

2x .htaccess copied below;

Webroot .htaccess (located in projectRoot/webroot/)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /apply/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Application .htaccess (located in projectRoot/)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /apply/
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Other answers say to change `RewriteBase` to `/`, but this isn't an option for me as I need it to be `/apply/`. 
A few other answers pointed to the `RewriteRule` being the issue, however removing these doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exclude the destination you are rewriting to :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /apply/
    RewriteRule ^$ webroot/ [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/webroot/
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Otherwise you will get a rewrite loop error, because /webroot/ also matches the pattern (.*)